# ActivePivot isAllMembersEnabled=false dimension default value

Tags: activepivot

How to specify what is the default member value, if we set the dimension isAllMembersEnabled=false.

sample data for the dimension are [A,B,C,D,E] and when I select the dimension I want the default value will be C.

Comment: Add this to config

  <level name="XXX" property="xxx">
   <comparator pluginKey="Custom">
    <order name="firstObjects">
     <value>C</value>
    </order>
   </comparator>
  </level>

then the default member of the dimension is always **C**

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it in the mdx context:

```
<mdxContext>
    <defaultMembers>
        <defaultMember dimensionName="name of your dimension">
            <defaultValue>[name of the level of C].[C]</defaultValue>
        </defaultMember>
    </defaultMembers>
</mdxContext>
```